# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'

Tags: c#

why `user = Console.ReadLine();` always got an error??

here are the errors:

- Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'
- Syntax error, '(' expected
- Syntax error, 'while' expected
- ) expected

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char user;
        do
        {
             Console.Clear();

             Console.WriteLine("Discount Code");
             Console.WriteLine("1. Student = 10%");
             Console.WriteLine("2. Senior  = 15%");
             Console.WriteLine("3. Regular = 0%");

             Console.Write("Please input discount code: ");
             int DiscountCode = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             fare fares = new fare();
             fares.setDiscountCode(DiscountCode);
             Console.WriteLine();
             Console.Write("Please input distance(KM):");
             double Distance = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             fares.setDistance(Distance);
             fares.getDistance();
             fares.totalFare();

         }
        user = Console.ReadLine(); // error
        while (user == 'y');

         Console.ReadKey();
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: After `do` block you need to write `while`, you can't write any other statements like `user = Console.ReadLine();` as well as `Console.ReadLine()` always will return string as mentioned in @Tim's answer

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns `string` and not `char`. If you just want to read single `char`, you can use `Console.ReadKey` instead. Try replacing line where you get error with below:

```
 user = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Answer (score -2):

Single quotes in C# `'y'` represent a `char`, while double-quotes `"y"` represent a `string`. `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, so it will never equal a char in the `while` statement.

Change to `string user;`

and `while (user == "y")`

Also, the while must immediately follow the `do` loop. (Thanks @Aren)

Comment: then `user` will still be of type char and not string.